# Vector Data being reset?

Tags: c++, vector

Carrying on from my previous question, which has now been solved:
[Issue with Pointers (Only in Release Build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044549/issue-with-pointers-only-in-release-build)

After making the required changes to the way i was creating enemies, i also had to change how other objects interact with the enemies for the obvious reasons. 
Now though, it seems that i'm doing something wrong again :/

Here i have some code for my projectiles that i create to hit the enemies, this one though does the opposite and stops the enemy for a short period of time.

```
if ((enemies[numOfEnemies].position.x + (enemies[numOfEnemies].width / 2) > bullet.position.x && 
            enemies[numOfEnemies].position.x < bullet.position.x + bullet.width) && 
            (enemies[numOfEnemies].position.y + (enemies[numOfEnemies].height / 2) > bullet.position.y &&
            enemies[numOfEnemies].position.y < bullet.position.y + bullet.height) && 
            enemies[numOfEnemies].speed != 0)
        {
            //We've collided with the wall, stop the enemy
            enemies[numOfEnemies].previousSpeed = enemies[numOfEnemies].speed;
            enemies[numOfEnemies].speed = 0;
        }
```

As you can see, simple stuff. But it seems that the enemies vector keeps being reset, unsure what's happening here. Before-hand, again worked perfectly well, with the changes since changing from pointers to vectors now has creating this issue :/.

```
void Towers::Update(std::vector<Enemies> enemies, SDLib& lib, Map cMap)
```

Thats how i'm passing in the vector to my function. Is the vector going out of scope and then being cleared up automatically? If so then what do i need to-do to assign the changes i make to the actual data?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "keeps being reset"?  Can you post some complete code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: `numOfEnemies` to me suggests that it is the number of enemies in the vector. If so, it would definitely not be a valid index. But then, it might just be a badly named in-range index.

Comment: Also, your coding style is awful and (potentially) sub-optimal. You should reduce the number of index operator calls to the bare minimum - just store the value of `enemies[numOfEnemies]` in local variable  (possibly a reference) and refer to it later in the member function.

Comment: I now see that you pass your vector by value. Is your problem maybe that the function modifies its argument, and you expect the passed vector to be changed? In that case, you need to muse a reference, just as you would need with an int. As is, your Update method gets (and possibly modifies) a _copy_ of the vector passed to it, while the original vector remains unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ function arguments are *pass-by-value*, unless otherwise specified.  That means that your function operates on a *copy* of the vector.  To have it modify the original, you need to pass by reference:

```
void Towers::Update(std::vector<Enemies> &enemies, SDLib& lib, Map cMap)
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your std::vector **by value**, which means it (including its contents) is copied each time it is passed to the function. If you want the Update() function to be able to change (the contents of) the vector, you need to pass it **by reference**:

```
void Towers::Update(std::vector<Enemies> &enemies, SDLib& lib, Map cMap)
```

The rest of your code can most likely stay the same, since references - as opposed to pointers - do not require explicit dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the vector to your function by value. So the original vector in the calling function will never be modified. Try this code that shows the issue:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int domod(std::vector<int>& v) {
        v[0] = 2;
}

int donotmod(std::vector<int> v) {
        v[0] = 2;
}

int main(void) {
        std::vector<int> v;

        v.push_back(1);

        donotmod(v);
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;

        domod(v);
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```